# APC resets after a few seconds

Tags: debugging, alternative-php-cache

Got a new server and the host installed APC for me.

Reloading apc.php shows that ACP resets itself every 4-6 seconds.
Uptime is always 0 and hits never go above 3000.

The site runs smoothly but if APC really starts over again & again, I'd like to fix that.

The error_log doesn't show errors. The only thing I can find is an cronjob error on running some php script `PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`.

Specs:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
SSD harddrive
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mod_python/3.3.1
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)
APC Version 3.1.7
```

apc.php snapshot:

```
Shared Memory   1 Segment(s) with 200.0 MBytes (mmap memory, pthread mutex Locks locking)
Start Time  31.05.2014 14:39:51
Uptime   0 minutes
File Upload Support 1
File Cache Information
Cached Files    161 (24.4 MBytes)
Hits    2423
Misses  161
Request Rate (hits, misses) 136.00 cache requests/second
Hit Rate    127.53 cache requests/second
Miss Rate   8.47 cache requests/second
Insert Rate 8.58 cache requests/second
Cache full count    0
User Cache Information
Cached Variables    0 (0.0 Bytes)
Hits    0
Misses  0
Request Rate (hits, misses) 0.00 cache requests/second
Hit Rate    0.00 cache requests/second
Miss Rate   0.00 cache requests/second
Insert Rate 0.00 cache requests/second
Cache full count    0
Runtime Settings
apc.cache_by_default    1
apc.canonicalize    1
apc.coredump_unmap  0
apc.enable_cli  0
apc.enabled 1
apc.file_md5    0
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters [path to my apc.php]
apc.gc_ttl  3600
apc.include_once_override   0
apc.lazy_classes    0
apc.lazy_functions  0
apc.max_file_size   2M
apc.mmap_file_mask  
apc.num_files_hint  7000
apc.preload_path    
apc.report_autofilter   0
apc.rfc1867 0
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
apc.serializer  default
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    200M
apc.slam_defense    1
apc.stat    0
apc.stat_ctime  0
apc.ttl 7200
apc.use_request_time    1
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl    7200
apc.write_lock  1
```

Comment: Relevant log file entries?

Comment: The error_log in my site's directory doesn't show errors. The only thing I can find is an cronjob error on running some php script `PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`. 
Any other log files to check?

Comment: `PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0.` That means there are two references trying to load that module. The first succeeds, the second complains it's already there.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is **mod_fcgid**
read its manual page:
http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html

impossible to share opcode cache, thats why you see different caches when apc is refreshed...
**suPHP** is evil too.

use **mod_fastcgi** with **php-fpm**

p.s. some apc configurations required to set **apc.enable_opcode_cache = 1**